# Firebase - Adding a user and add other info to user record. - error

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have added a registration process in my app. When a new user sign up, the user is created. I am getting the new userID. But, when I want to add a subcollection to the userID, I am getting an error.

> error: Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/not-found] Some requested document was not found.

The new user is created properly and he is then sent to the homePage.

I do not understand what I am missing. Thank you.

Here is the code.

```
Future<void> _createUser() async {
    try {
      UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: controllerEmail!.text, password: controllerPassword!.text);

      print(userCredential.user?.uid);

     await saveNameUserInFireBase(userCredential.user?.uid);


    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {

      if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
             print('The password provided is too weak !!');

      } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
             print('The account already exists for that email !!');

    } else if (e.code == 'invalid-email') {
            print('This email seems to be invalid. Please, check it !!');

      } else if (e.code == 'operation-not-allowed') {
            print('Registration process is not working. Please, try later !!');

      }

      firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage
      print("error: $e");
    } catch (e) {

      controllerFirstName!.text = "";
      controllerLastName!.text = "";
      controllerEmail!.text = "";
      controllerPassword!.text = "";
      controllerUserName!.text = "";

      print("error: $e");
    }

  }
```

```
Future <void> saveNameUserInFireBase (String? userID) async {

    if (userID != null) {

      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('Users')
          .doc(userID)
          .update
        ({
        'firstName': controllerFirstName!.text,
        'lastName': controllerLastName!.text,
        'email': controllerEmail!.text,
      });

    }

  }
```

[image]

Comment: Share code for when you create the user.

Comment: it is shared already. _createUser()

Comment: change the update method to `set()`